# c++ get a vector from a map of vectors

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector, stdmap

I have a map of vector

```
map< int, vector<float> > hit = getAlignedHits();
```

I want to get the vector paired with a specific key, such as:

```
vector<float> vec;
vec = hit[1];
```

The error I get is:

> candidate function not
>         viable: no known conversion from `vector<float, allocator<float>>` to `const vector<double, allocator<double>>` for
>   1st argument
>       `vector& operator=(const vector& __x);`

I tried below, didn't work:

```
    &vec =  hit[1];
```

> error: expression is not assignable

I also tried below, didn't work:

```
    map< int, vector<float> >::iterator itr;
    itr = hit.find(1);
    &vec =  itr->second;
```

> error: expression is not assignable

Does anyone know why these doesn't work, and how I can get the vector from the map?

Thanks a lot in advance

Edit:
Here is what getAlignedHits does and the variables I used there:

```
const int NLayer = 6;,  vector<float> *hit_position; double alignmentpar[NLayer];


 map< int, vector<float> > getAlignedHits(){
    double newpos;
    for (int i=0; i<NLayer; i++) {
        vector<float> bla;
        bla.clear();
        hit[i] = bla;
    }

    for (unsigned int ihit=0; ihit<layerID->size(); ihit++) {
        newpos = hit_position->at(ihit) - alignmentpar[layerID->at(ihit)];
        hit[layerID->at(ihit)].push_back(newpos);
    }

 }
```

Comment: shouldn't `vec - itr->second;` work? also the error seems to indicate you're calling some `const` method, additionally you should always compare the iterator returned from `find` with the `end()` of the map: `if (itr != hit.end()) vec = itr->second;`

Comment: I believe there is something else that you don't show us that causes this error. This seems fine.

Comment: @EdChum look at your error messages, your example code doesn't match the error. The error says that you're doing `vector<double> vec; map< int, vector<float> > hit; vec = hit[1];`

Comment: Is `hit` really a local variable? Or is it a field of some `const`ant object?

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/cUUC8n)

Comment: @StoryTeller I agree, I've voted to close. I'll retract if information demonstrating the actual problem is presented.

Comment: Shouldn't `getAlignedHits()` return something? Just saying.

Comment: I fixed the markup of your error. You didn't present the code the produces it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me

```
std::vector<float> & h0 = hit[0];
```

or simpler

```
auto & h0 = hit[0];
```

A full example

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
 {
   std::map< int, std::vector<float> > hit { { 0, {} } };

   std::vector<float> & h0a = hit[0];
   auto & h0b = hit[0];

   h0a.push_back(2.3);

   std::cout << hit[0].front() << std::endl;
   std::cout << h0a.front() << std::endl;
   std::cout << h0b.front() << std::endl;

   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Yup, it works. But why does the OP have an error?

Comment: @storyTeller - I suspect he's doing something like `std::vector<float> vec; & vec = hit[0];`

Comment: Yes, I was doing that :), fixed it, std::vector<float> & h0a = hit[0]; worked.   Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Certainly,

```
 &vec =  ... <something>
```

will not work, since you cannot assign to the address of a variable something, however:

> candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'vector>' to 'const vector>' for 1st argument vector& operator=(const vector& __x);

gives me a feeling that you are trying to do this assignment in a `const` function, or on an object which has some constness applied to it. Please share more "original" code so that we can spot the error.

Comment: look at the source of his comment, the actual error says `conversion from 'vector<float, allocator<float>>' to 'const vector<double, allocator<double>>'`

Comment: @PeterT does it? I don't see any mention of `double` in the OP. I even did a textual search in the webpage.

Comment: @StoryTeller that's because the stackoverflow markup swallowed it, click on "edit" on his question and you'll see

Comment: @PeterT, fancy that. Thanks for teaching me not to blindly trust the rendered output.

Comment: this swallowing error maybe should be presented as a possible enhancement to the stackoverflow folks?

Comment: I edited the question with more info. I changed double to float, sorry I wrote here wrong. Now it is vector<float> vec in the code.

Comment: @EdaYıldırım please fix more, `const NLayer = 6;,`  is not valid C++. and `hit` is not declared anywhere